# AWS cognito Identity provider: api.twitter.com Invalid login token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, twitter-oauth

```
        IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
        Logins: {
            "api.twitter.com": combinedToken,
        }
    }));

    if (!getIdResponse.IdentityId) {
        throw new Error('No IdentityId returned from GetIdCommand');
    }

    const credentialsResponse = await cognitoIdClient.send(new GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand({
        IdentityId: getIdResponse.IdentityId,
        Logins: {
            "api.twitter.com": combinedToken,
        }
    }));
```

request payload

```
{
    "IdentityPoolId": "eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx",// my identity pool id
    "Logins": {
        "api.twitter.com": "GFy5FwAAAAABrVmwAAABjElMvO4;E6fn05h8QZkvZcn4WkO3A7qWpBuTgmMc" // i get them from the request everytime
    }
}
```

request response

{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Invalid login token."}

in aws i have add the correct
keys that i used to generate the tokens in the code

[image]

that i get them like this

```
        const requestData = {
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { oauth_callback: 'http://localhost:3000/CallbackPage/' }, // Your server-side callback URL
        };

        const authHeader = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(requestData));

        const response = await axios.post(requestData.url, null, { headers: { Authorization: authHeader['Authorization'], 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } });
        const responseParams = new URLSearchParams(response.data);

        const requestToken = responseParams.get('oauth_token');
        const requestTokenSecret = responseParams.get('oauth_token_secret');

        if (!requestToken || !requestTokenSecret) {
            throw new Error('Failed to obtain request token or secret');
        }

        // Send the requestToken and requestTokenSecret to the client
        res.status(200).json({ requestToken, requestTokenSecret });
```

to get the correct response from AWS and check what is wrong in my process